# Chrome App install banner - Dismissed user install

Tags: google, chrome

In Chrome 43 Google added the feature to show an app installer popup out of Chrome and to get the feedback if the user added or dismissed the home install.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/increasing-engagement-with-app-install-banners-in-chrome-for-android

What do you think, how should we handle the "Dismissed" action?

1. Sure, we can store the user decision in our database to get statistics. But I assume this will also be available to Google Analytics
2. Do you think we should show the prompt again after a certain time?

Answer (score 1):

This question is likely to have subjective answers so I thought I'd throw my hat in

**My (*hiccup* Uneducated) Opinion**

1. Yes, you should ask the user if he would like to again
2. But only if he shows real engagement with the site and goes to it regularly.
3. It should always be an option for him to do add it in the settings

**Similarities**

Adding a homescreen file reminds me a lot of rating systems. 
Apps often remind you to rate them if you have been using them long enough. The consensus on this is that you show them an option to do something nice for us (the app makers) and for themselves (so Google can suggest better apps) at minimal disturbance.

Most apps do this after a while and most people are fine with it. In fact I'm pretty sure it leads to more ratings.

Here are some information on rating systems

1. [Rate Now, Remind Me Later, Never Remind Me Again](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/64468/rate-now-remind-me-later-never-remind-me-again)
2. [Should I ask users to rate my app with pop-up window?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/51106/should-i-ask-users-to-rate-my-app-with-pop-up-window)

Comment: 1. So you mean once a month the user should be prompted for this "add to homescreen", if he still uses the application?
2. Anyone know if Google Analytics shows some kind of reporting for this reason?